# Update a subset of a df with mutate_each

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `dplyr` dataframe with 100k+ rows and ~200 columns. There are about 15 columns which contain date values in Excel format (# of days since Jan 1, 1900), their column names contain the `date` string which makes it fairly easy to subset the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(date1 = 45000+ 500*rnorm(100),
           date2 = 50000+ 500*rnorm(100),
           var1 = 50 * rnorm(100),
           var2 = 100 + 20 * rnorm(100))

> x %>% head
     date1    date2       var1      var2
1 44952.83 49432.88   8.125523 125.95802
2 44331.47 49231.76 -34.814162 117.26881
3 44597.69 49651.91  27.747881 108.45787
4 45113.50 49802.87  24.584569  83.84904
5 46212.14 49972.59  72.444414  80.61595
6 45753.38 50074.57 -34.927552 127.70018

date_cols <- x %>% select(contains('date', ignore.case=T)) %>% names
> date_cols
[1] "date1" "date2"
```

I'd like to change these date columns to actual `R` datetimes without changing the other columns. I just can't figure out how to update only the `date_cols` subset of my dataframe:

```
x %>% select_(.dots = date_cols) %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(as.Date(., origin="1900-01-01"))) %>% 
      head

       date1      date2
1 2023-01-28 2035-05-05
2 2021-05-17 2034-10-16
3 2022-02-07 2035-12-10
4 2023-07-08 2036-05-09
5 2026-07-11 2036-10-26
6 2025-04-08 2037-02-05
```

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
x %>% select_(.dots = date_cols) <- x %>% select_(.dots = date_cols) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.Date(., origin="1900-01-01")))
```

I guess there is a better way to "rbinding" the original dataframe without the date columns with the `date_cols`subset once mutated.

Comment: You can specify columns in `mutate_each` after `funs`. Also see the new (0.5.0) `mutate_at` and `mutate_if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented @alistaire, you can use `mutate_at` to convert only those `date` columns and keep the rest of the data frames unchanged, so that you can avoid binding the original data frame with the subsets:

```
library(dplyr)
muX <- x %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('date')), funs(as.Date(., origin="1900-01-01")))

head(muX)
#        date1      date2       var1      var2
# 1 2021-11-09 2038-10-20  44.524710  86.15957
# 2 2020-06-04 2037-08-04  31.402905  94.74633
# 3 2023-12-22 2038-03-06  31.600929  85.90605
# 4 2020-05-08 2037-01-02   7.140777  82.80565
# 5 2025-03-25 2038-07-30 -54.913577 100.83949
# 6 2021-02-18 2034-06-20  28.616670  93.92246
```

And also according to `?mutate_at`:

> summarise_each() and mutate_each() are older variants that will be
>   deprecated in the future.

Better get used to these new APIs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer but I'd really appreciate if you could also give the syntax that would work in a pipeline (using `.`operators) and without explicitly defining `date_cols` ? I've tried but to no avail.

Comment: These are fairly new features. I haven't experimented much yet, but I can try.

Comment: Maybe something like this. `muX <- x %>% mutate_at(grep('date', names(.), value = T), funs(as.Date(., origin="1900-01-01")))` Maybe not the best but fairly concise.

Comment: A better way, I believe. `muX <- x %>% mutate_at(contains('date', vars = names(.)), funs(as.Date(., origin="1900-01-01")))`

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you consider this a better alternative?

Comment: Well, may be not. I am just thinking the `contains` function is from `dplyr` package.